# How do I add "Not found" in to this search without looping whole list? C#

Tags: c#, loops, search

```
int[] array = {0, 10, 2, 6, 7, 9, 88, 97, 97, 78}        
Console.Write("Search for number: "); 
int search = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for(int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
{
    if(array[index] == search)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(search + " is at index: " + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of printing and instantly forgetting the index, _save it in a variable_. and check it after you've completed the loop. and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You can `break;` the loop to exit once you've found what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean, to determine whether an item is not in the list, you're going to have to check every element, whichever way you look at it

Comment: You could just do `if(array.Contains(search))` and do the "Not found" in the `else` part, but that will still iterate the entire array.

Comment: Sorry for the poor layout of the question. The purpose was to get an answer on how to look for the "wrong" number in the array without the program printing "not found" ten times. Not found condition, but I used the wrong condition. I changed it to if else (array [index] <= 0) and added a break statement to the end. Now the program works as it should.      else if(array[index] <= 0){
                        
        Console.WriteLine(search + " was not found");
        break;

Answer (score 1):

You should save the index in the loop. Then you can reuse it after the loop without iterating the array again. Another, better way is to use [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0)

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, search);
string msg = index == -1 ? "not found" : $"{search} is at index {index}";
Console.WriteLine(msg);
```